# OpenMP parallelize for loop slower than sequential

Tags: c++, c++11, openmp

I am trying to improve the performance of a commandline tool by making full use of all cores available.I choose openmp because it doesn't change the semantics much and is pretty straightforward for beginners like me.I profiled the program to find out what loops run a lot of times(300+) and looking to parallelize those in an attempt to make the software faster.

```
#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:sum)
    for (int j = minx; j <= maxx; ++j) {
      sum += row_in[j] * kernel[j - x + offset];
    }
```

The code above gives the correct output with OpenMP but is several order of magnitude slower than the sequential version.

P.S 
I am open for suggestion for making loops with smaller interations(3-7) faster as they can get many times

Comment: I can speculate many things, but a minimal example can be very helpful

Comment: If the loop count is of the order of 300, simd reduction should be much more efficient than parallel reduction. You  may have other examples where omp parallel for suggests removal of auto vectorization.  Some of these details are compiler dependent.

Comment: Perhaps, if you would use inner_product () where it fits, you might not go to as much excess with parallel for.

Comment: Are you measuring the loop or overall program runtime, do you perform a warmup run? Depending on the implementation, initialisation of the runtime and thread-creation can be performed lazy (first parallel region) and be very costly. I.e. the loop might be faster, but the overhead kills you for small workloads/benchmarks. Also, as @tim18 stated, `simd` might be better option here.